# Reverse dictionary (key to sequence of values) search with NoSQL database

Tags: nosql, bookmark-lookup

Suppose we have a dictionary that maps keys to sequences of values - for example:

- potato: A, B, C
- tomato: B
- lettuce: C
- carrot: A, C
- cucumber: C

I would like to perform queries such as:

- query A, B, C returns potato
- query C returns lettuce, cucumber (order shouldn't matter)

I understand that the reverse dictionary lookup could be done with normalized relational databases (as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749201/building-a-reverse-language-dictionary) post). However, my intuition is that a non relational database could better fit this problem, like a graph. Additionally, I'm looking for something read-optimized.

Is there a NoSQL database that fits this kind of problem? Where should I direct my search for such an implementation?